# Программа или плагин хрома открытия страницы сайта если нет активности

Tags: html, windows

Делаю информационный киоск, возникают вопросы которые нужно решать. В данном случае это костыль автоматического открытия главной страницы если нет активности пользователя, как в терминалах киви после какого то времени открывается вновь главное окно или как в банкоматах.

Comment: Может просто добавить JS редирект на все страницы по таймауту в браузере?

Comment: я нашел почти идеальный код http://myrusakov.ru/javascript-noactive-user.html   подскажите как сделать переход на сайт вместо алерта и добавить исключение домена где не будет работать таймер